# Checking between inherited class and super

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance, casting

I have a class:

```
class User: NSObject {
    var name = "User_Name"
    // Other variables and methods
}
```

and a second class which is inherited from 'user':

```
class Employee: User {
    var job = "Manager"
    // other variables and methods
}
```

I want to be able to check between the two in a function and act on them slightly differently.

I believe I can use a guard statement to cast my 'AnyObject' parameter to a suspected type before using it but don't know how to check between two different class types. For instance, i believe I can do the following on one type:

```
func addUser(user : AnyObject) {
    guard let user = user as? User else {return}
        // do something with 'user' which is known to be of type 'User'
    }
```

but cannot figure out how to check if the parameter sent is an Employee if it's not of type 'User'. If the guard statements evaluate true I want to do very similar actions, regardless of if it's a User or Employee and so think there must be a way to do it without duplicating code.

Can someone point me in the right direction for testing between two types, please?

Comment: Unrelated but why are you extending `NSObject`? Only do so if you have a clear and understood reason.

Comment: I thought this was required when creating a new class which had no superclass? Is it not? what are the reasons you talk about?

Comment: @AlTopping no, there's no need for a custom class to inherit from any existing class, so unless you explicitly need some functionality from another class, don't inherit from it

Comment: In Objective-C, you must have a base class. But not in Swift.

Comment: Thanks for all comments; you've both been really helpful. Al

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `AnyObject` is rarely the right way to go. Usually you would want to implement a generic function when you want specific implementations of the same function based on the type of the input argument. However, since you only need your function to work on objects having the same superclass, you can simply use the superclass as the input argument type, then use optional casting to see if the argument is actually of the more specific type.

```
func addUser(user: User) {
    if let employee = user as? Employee {
        print(employee.job)
    } else {
        print(user.name)
    }
}

addUser(user: User()) //prints "User_Name"
addUser(user: Employee()) //prints "Manager"
```

For this simple case, there's no need for a generic function, especially since the generic function would take pretty much the same form as the non-generic one in this case:

```
func addUser<T:User>(user: T){
    if let employee = user as? Employee {
        print(employee.job)
    } else {
        print(user.name)
    }
}

addUser(user: User()) //prints "User_Name"
addUser(user: Employee()) //prints "Manager"
```

Or if you want to extend it to work on classes not inheriting from `User` as well:

```
func addUser<T>(user: T){
    if let user = user as? User {
        if let employee = user as? Employee {
            print(employee.job)
        } else {
            print(user.name)
        }
    } else {
        print("Not a user")
    }
}

addUser(user: User()) //prints "User_Name"
addUser(user: Employee()) //prints "Manager"
addUser(user: "Me") //prints "Not a user"
```

Comment: David, this looks spot on. 

For future information, however, how would i implement a generic function to do this kind of thing?

Comment: Thanks for this too David